# HMAC apisign in a requests headers but headers must be str error?

Tags: python, python-requests, hmac

```
    apikey = '$mykey'
    apisecret = '$mykeysecret'
    nonce = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
    uri = 'https://somewebsite.com/api/v1.5/account/getbalances?apikey='+apikey+'&nonce='+nonce
    sign = hmac.new(b'apisecret', b'uri', hashlib.sha512)
    response = requests.get(uri, headers={'apisign': sign}, timeout=10)
    print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

 """ The following are the example provided by the website """
    # $ch = curl_init($uri);
    # curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
    # $execResult = curl_exec($ch);
    # $obj = json_decode($execResult);
    # url = "https://somewebsite.com/api/v1.5/account/getbalances?apikey=API_KEY"
```

I just can't solve this after 2 hours of research. It now says headers need to be str. But using str{'apisign': sign} it says str object has no item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the dictionary correctly into the headers argument, but error is saying the value of `sign` is not a string.  `sign` is a HMAC object and needs to be converted to a string:

```
>>> print(sign)
<hmac.HMAC object at 0x03337950>
```

I would take a look at calling `sign.digest()` to see if it returns the string you are expecting.  If it is, then you can replace `headers={'apisign': sign}` with `headers={'apisign': sign.digest()}`.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. This is exactly the problem. I got it in the last minute finding in other people's code, but he used "sign.hexdigest()" and it worked.